# Chaining NAND gates does not work and results in wrong simulation with LTspice

Tags: ltspice, logic-gates, nand

I started building basic logic gates. I wanted to start basic and understandable so I started building some NAND gates just using two transistors. On its own hooked up to a switch and a LED they work as they should, so I continued chaining them.

I first tried to simulate this circuit using LTspice where everything looked fine. However testing them out with hardware does not result the same way. I chained 4 NAND gates to form a XOR gate. If I add an extra NAND gate like shown below, the output of the XOR gate does not work anymore.

[image: XOR and NAND gate circuit build from NAND gates]

The probes are as follow:

1. V2
2. V3
3. Q19 Collector
4. Q5 Collector

[image: LTspice simulation result]

But my measurements (in V) are (* means using 1k for all pull-up resistors):

| V2 | V3 | Q19 Collector | Q5 Collector | Q19 Collector * | Q5 Collector * |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.00 | 5.00 | 0.03 | 5.00 | 3.10 | 4.18 |
| 0 | 5.00 | 2.22 | 1.36 | 3.70 | 2.88 |
| 5.00 | 0 | 5.00 | 0.08 | 3.33 | 2.86 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.03 | 1.36 | 2.69 | 2.88 |

This is my circuit build on a breadboard (same wire colors are connected together, except the green and red going out of the picture are where I measured the values. And the black and yellow wires are where I set my input signals):
[image: Circuit build on breadboard]

My questions are:

1. Why is the LTspice simulation wrong ([This](https://pastebin.com/ipD5KZrg) is my asc file)?
2. Why does this behave like that and how can I get the gates to work as they should?

Comment: Don't your gates depend on relative current gain of the transistors? What if the upper one had twice the gain?

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t get what you mean. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Make your collector resistor smaller (1kΩ).  TTL could sink a lot of current, but source depends on pullup resistors.

Comment: I can test 1k out, but why does this work in the simulation? 
Isn’t that circuit design called RTL (resistor-transistor-logic)? From what I understand TTL NAND gates use multi emitter transistors and they don’t waste current if both inputs are high?

Comment: I'm too lazy (or tired?) to simulate it, but when the upper transistor has more current gain, \$V_{CE}\$ of the lower one should be higher than that of the upper one, leading to an unwelcome high voltage at the output - enough to "open the next lower transistor". The difference the third input at the first gate output makes is going from a 10k:5k+ voltage divider to 10k:3.3k+, compounding to the problem: output pull-ups should probably be one tenth of input resistors.

Comment: I also agree with the others in trying 1kΩ as your pullup resistor values.  You should look up the term "fan-out" for logic gates, as I believe you are running into a fan-out issue.  Going to be difficult to determine the discrepancy between your simulation and the real-world circuit without having the real-world circuit right in front of us.

Comment: I tried 1k out and edited my initial post with the results. They are even worse. I already came across the word fan-out. I read that it can be calculated by measuring the input (does that mean I have to measure both and add them up as I have two inputs?) and output current and dividing them? But my real question is why this doesn't work, and why the simulation is wrong?

Comment: `They are even worse` I didn't expect *that*. Please add the voltage at R1 (you made that 1k too, didn't you).

Comment: All the transistors on your breadboard are flipped backwards.  I think you have C and E mixed up.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUtma.png

Comment: Damn, you're right, I had the pinout of the SS8050 in mind which I was using before. Interesting, that the BC547 have it flipped. I'll try that out tomorrow as well measure the voltage on R1. (My picture has every resistor as 10k, but of corse I tested it out with all five pull-ups 1k (R1, R10, R28, R4, R7))

Comment: This was the solution. The transistors where collector and emitter flipped. Now the circuit works like simulated (also with 10k pullups). Thank you for that tip. I guess because C and E have the same dotation it kind of worked, but not really, because they are sized differently and so current could not flow like it should?

Comment: The next step would be to build it incorrectly in LTspice and probe around various voltages and currents to get an idea of how it was operating like that.  It's still worth noting that it's best practice with these types of circuits to heed @greybeard 's advice of "output pull-ups should probably be one tenth of input resistors" so you have more stable logic levels as your circuit grows with more NAND gates attached.

Comment: You are very welcome to answer your own question. (Try selecting the specimen with highest&lowest current gain@\$I_C .2 mA, V_{CE} 1 V, using them as "upper&lower transistor". Measure, swap, repeat measurement. You are very welcome to report results.)

Comment: (Good luck implementing the logic of a 7423, a CD4048.)

Comment: Sorry, but I think analyzing this goes beyond my knowledge. I'll try to use 1k's, but this increases current. My actual plan is to add some totem-pole end stages at the end of each formation of NAND gate to make this block modular. Is that a good idea?